# java sql connections via class 

Tags: java, instance-variables

Hy i have the following code :

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.net.*;

public class binsz {

    public void dbConnect(String db_connect_string, String username, String password) {
        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_string, username, password);
            // System.out.println("connected");
            }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public void dbQuery(String query) {
        try {
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String db_name = "sqlserver.local";
        String username = "sa";
        String password = "passwordforsa";
        String connection = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + db_name;

        Connection conn = null;
        binsz db = new binsz();
        db.dbConnect(connection, username, password);
        String query = "SELECT TOP 2 * FROM aux..table_name";
        db.dbQuery(query);
    }

}
```

and it gives an error while compiling it :

```
binsz.java:20: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable conn
location: class sip_bins
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                             ^
1 error
```

How can I use `binsz db = new binsz();` to execute a query and retrieve it's values .

Thanks

PS: the connection to the database is working .. (it prints "connected" if I uncomment that line) ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty awful code - useless as written.  You've got a lot of work to do.

I'd recommend that you study this and throw your code away:

```
package persistence;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * util.DatabaseUtils
 * User: Michael
 * Date: Aug 17, 2010
 * Time: 7:58:02 PM
 */
public class DatabaseUtils {
    private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:database";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "password";
/*
    private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";
    private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/party";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "pgsuper";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "pgsuper";
*/
/*
    private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/party";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "party";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "party";
*/

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long begTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        String driver = ((args.length > 0) ? args[0] : DEFAULT_DRIVER);
        String url = ((args.length > 1) ? args[1] : DEFAULT_URL);
        String username = ((args.length > 2) ? args[2] : DEFAULT_USERNAME);
        String password = ((args.length > 3) ? args[3] : DEFAULT_PASSWORD);

        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            connection = createConnection(driver, url, username, password);
            DatabaseMetaData meta = connection.getMetaData();
            System.out.println(meta.getDatabaseProductName());
            System.out.println(meta.getDatabaseProductVersion());

            String sqlQuery = "SELECT PERSON_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME FROM PERSON ORDER BY LAST_NAME";
            System.out.println("before insert: " + query(connection, sqlQuery, Collections.EMPTY_LIST));

            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            String sqlUpdate = "INSERT INTO PERSON(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES(?,?)";
            List parameters = Arrays.asList("Foo", "Bar");
            int numRowsUpdated = update(connection, sqlUpdate, parameters);
            connection.commit();

            System.out.println("# rows inserted: " + numRowsUpdated);
            System.out.println("after insert: " + query(connection, sqlQuery, Collections.EMPTY_LIST));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            rollback(connection);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            close(connection);
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("wall time: " + (endTime - begTime) + " ms");
        }
    }

    public static Connection createConnection(String driver, String url, String username, String password) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName(driver);
        if ((username == null) || (password == null) || (username.trim().length() == 0) || (password.trim().length() == 0)) {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        } else {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        }
    }

    public static void close(Connection connection) {
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void close(Statement st) {
        try {
            if (st != null) {
                st.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void close(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void rollback(Connection connection) {
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.rollback();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static List<Map<String, Object>> map(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        List<Map<String, Object>> results = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
                int numColumns = meta.getColumnCount();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= numColumns; ++i) {
                        String name = meta.getColumnName(i);
                        Object value = rs.getObject(i);
                        row.put(name, value);
                    }
                    results.add(row);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            close(rs);
        }
        return results;
    }

    public static List<Map<String, Object>> query(Connection connection, String sql, List<Object> parameters) throws SQLException {
        List<Map<String, Object>> results = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            int i = 0;
            for (Object parameter : parameters) {
                ps.setObject(++i, parameter);
            }
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            results = map(rs);
        } finally {
            close(rs);
            close(ps);
        }
        return results;
    }

    public static int update(Connection connection, String sql, List<Object> parameters) throws SQLException {
        int numRowsUpdated = 0;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            int i = 0;
            for (Object parameter : parameters) {
                ps.setObject(++i, parameter);
            }
            numRowsUpdated = ps.executeUpdate();
        } finally {
            close(ps);
        }
        return numRowsUpdated;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't I get any results out of that ?

Comment: and you removed object `db` used in `db.dbQuery(conn, query)`

Comment: and it also worked in the first place with `private Connection conn` and I also do retrive results by adding a `while rs.next() in dbQuery`

Comment: You create a ResultSet and neither pass it out nor map it into any object.    When it goes out of scope it's gone.  Useless.

Comment: Yes, I did remove the object db.  I made the methods static.  Read the code.

Comment: How can I map the ResultSet to an object or pass it out ?

Comment: Took it out.  It should be static.

Comment: Either return the ResultSet (bad idea) instead of void or create an object, iterate through the ResultSet to load the values into the object, and then close the ResultSet.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `Connection conn` which is currently in the method `dbConnect` as an instance variable. You get this error because `conn` is unknown in the method `dbQuery`.

Comment: Make it private Connection conn and move it to directly after the opening braces of the class declaration. You can leave the assignment to conn in the method dbConnect.

Comment: Man .. I don't know that .. that's why I'm asking .. can you provide a direct answer .. because this is tralalal to me ..

Answer (score 0):

You should make connection an instance variable `this.conn = DriverManager...`. 
I would also recommend using a good connection pool.

Also remember to close your statements, result-sets and connections after you are finished with them.

**UPDATE**

```
try {
    ...
} finally {
    if (rs != null) rs.close();
    if (st != null) st.close();
    //if (conn != null) conn.close(); // depends on wheter you need it again, or whil retrieve a new one
}
```

Comment: that .. finally statement in which method is used ?

Comment: where you do your query... in dbQuery()

Answer (score 0):

What is conn here?

```
 Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
```

in the method

```
public void dbQuery(String query)
```

You need to declare conn as an instance variable if you want multiple methods of your class to access it.

Comment: private Connection conn; inside class as instance var and then remove declaration for Connection conn in dbConnect method

Answer (score 0):

you have:

```
public void dbConnect(String db_connect_string, String username, String password)
```

and the call:

```
db.dbConnect(connection, username, password);
```

You should change it to:

```
public void dbConnect(Connection conn, String username, String password) {
   ...
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_string, username, password);
   ...
}
```

and the usage:

```
db.dbConnect(conn, username, password);
```

also you should change the signature of your method to:

```
public void dbQuery(String query, Connection conn);
```

and the usage to:

```
db.dbQuery(query, conn);
```